# Django query data btween date and time

Tags: ajax, django, django-models, django-views

How do I query data between two date and time from django model.

I am using below code but it is not working. Here In Db for every second data is populated and from browser **every second or minute or hours or current date or week,** a Ajax is request sent.

However  currently I am not filtering the data based upon they date+ time  because of this server takes time to respond. Please guide me how do I query data model between date+time

```
tempresult=Realtimekwhrtu1.objects.filter(datetime_published__range=(
               datetime.datetime.combine('2008-03-27',datetime.time.min),
                datetime.datetime.combine('2008-03-27',datetime.time.max)))
```

**JSON example:**

```
{
"data": [{
    "date": "11/25/2016 08:59:58",
    "energy": 29940935080,
    "power": 6815.7056798623,
    "time": 217781943
}, {
    "date": "11/25/2016 09:29:59",
    "energy": 29940981851,
    "power": 6803.7187250996,
    "time": 217783743
}, {
    "date": "11/25/2016 09:59:59",
    "energy": 29941028913,
    "power": 6841.5804195804,
    "time": 217785544
}, {
    "date": "11/25/2016 10:29:59",
    "energy": 29941075952,
    "power": 6845.9247648903,
    "time": 217787343
}, {
    "date": "11/25/2016 10:59:58",
    "energy": 29941123228,
    "power": 6877.2764478764,
    "time": 217789143
}]
```

}

Comment: `datetime.combine` take two arguments `date` and `time` [combine](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine)

Comment: Could yop please give me an example or code